# Disable changing workspace loop

Tags: configuration, xubuntu, xfce

Lets say I have two workspaces and the fist one is active.
If I change workspace <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> twice, I change to workspace 2 then 1 again.

What I want is to disable that feature. When I am on workspace two, I want it to be blocked to it when moving to the right.

I know it is possible to do it on ubuntu but I did not manage to find the option on xubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If still needed: open xfce4-settings, go to 'Window Manager Tweaks', switch to 'Workspaces' tab and disable 'Wrap workspaces depending on actual desktop layout' and 'Wrap workspaces when the first or the last workspace is reached' options.

Answer (score 1):

with this method you can work with only one workspace but it will do. Add xfce workspace applet to the panel right click it and add only 1 workspace there or go into xfce4 setting , workspace and add only 1 workspace and you are done